# Derivation of the von Neumann divergence $d_{vN}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, information-theory

In slide 16 of the work "Kernel Learning with Bregman Matrix Divergences" [1], it is shown that for matrices $X$ and $Y$, s.t. $X=V\Lambda V^T$  and $Y=U\Phi U ^T$, the von Neumann divergence can be written as:

$$D_{vN} = tr(X log X - X log Y - X + Y)$$
$$= \sum_i \lambda_i log \lambda_i - \sum_{i,j} (v_i^T u_j )\lambda_i log \theta_j -\sum_i (\lambda_i -\theta_i)$$

What I don't understand is how the author reaches the second line from the first one.

Remark: The author assumes to sort the eigenvalues for both matrices [2], Theorem 6 page 11.

[1] https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/inderjit/Talks/stanford_kernel.pdf

[2] https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume10/kulis09a/kulis09a.pdf

Comment: What did you try and where are you stuck? Can you explain where the $\sum_i (\lambda_i - \theta_i)$ comes from? Can you explain where the $\sum \lambda_i \log \lambda_i$ comes from? What definitions and properties of traces are you familiar with?

Comment: Indeed, I cannot explain where the two terms $\sum \lambda_i log \lambda_i$ and $\sum_{i,j} (v_i^T u_j )\lambda_i log \theta_j$ are coming from.

Comment: Okay, so I guess you're aware of the additivity of trace and the fact that we can decompose the expression into four separate traces. Keeping things general, the first question is perhaps this - if $A = P D P^T,$ where $P$ is orthogonal and $D$ diagonal (and positive definite), can you express $\log A$ in terms of $P$ and $D$? Secondly, recall that $\mathrm{tr}(A) = \sum_{i} A_{ii}$. Working with this, can you come up with an expression for $\mathrm{tr}(AB)$ in terms of the entries of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Okay, thanks, I think I got the first part: 
$tr(A log A) = tr(PDP^T log(PDP^T))=tr(PD log(D') P^T)= tr(P^T PD log(D')) = tr(D log(D'))$, where $D'$ contains the log of the diagonal elements of $D$. The rest is clear.
Nice teaching. What about the second part? It contains the eigenvectors.

Comment: Try to derive the formula $\mathrm{tr}(AB) = \sum_{i,j} A_{ij} B_{ij}$. Coupling this with an expression for $A_{ij}$ using $A = V DV^T$ and $B_{ij}$ using $B = UEU^T$ should give an expression that massages to a nice form.This will be easier if you work in the eigenbasis of $A$ (so that $A = D$ and $B = P E P^T,$ where $P = V^T U$). Now setting $D = \Lambda$ and $E = \log \Theta$ would give the expression (note btw that there's an error in the Q - the expression should have $(v_i^T u_j)^2$).